# Convert formatted string to table of tables

Tags: string, lua, lua-table, formatted

In Lua, is there any way to split this string:

```
etc3=1336,etc2=14477,etc4=1335,etc1=1337
```

into this table?

```
tbl = {
    { 'etc3', 1336 },
    { 'etc2', 14477 },
    { 'etc4', 1335 },
    { 'etc1', 1337 },
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You probably need to split the string into its sub parts, look at [SplitJoin](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SplitJoin).

Comment: looks like valid Lua syntax - you could [`loadstring()`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-loadstring) it. In a secured environment, if you don't trust the source.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
local str = 'etc3=1336,etc2=14477,etc4=1335,etc1=1337'
local tbl = {}
for k, v in str:gmatch'(%w+)=(%d+)' do
  tbl[#tbl+1] = {k, tonumber(v)}
end
```